# Are there any functions for working with the contents of X.509 Certificates in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, function, certificate, x509

I have a SecCertificateRef representing an X.509 certificate. Does Cocoa Touch have any libraries for working with the contents of the certificate (I couldn't find any), or will I need to parse the DER representation of the certificate myself? Parsing is not a problem, however I'd prefer to save some time if I overlooked some functionality? Or perhaps you can recommend any good third party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into openssl - a quick google search for "openssl with cocoa" shows pretty good results, you should be able to integrate fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in cocoa touch layer to process the certificate. APIs  to process certificates are in core service layer. plz check in developer.apple.com for Certificate, Key, and Trust Services APIs

Answer (score 0):

The (brilliant) [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) project includes an [`X509Certificate`](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/RunLoop/Xcode/CertTest/X509Certificate.h) class that does all the hard work for you and returns a nice `NSDictionary`. I highly recommend it.